# How did Adam and Hawwa multiply?

Tags: history, sunni, shiism, prophet-adam, adam-and-eve

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidil-Mursalin wa 'ala 'Alihi wa Sahbihi Ajma'in.

---

So the question is **How did Adam and Hawwa multiply?**

I'd like to know both Sunni and Shia views.

Answer (score 1):

Adam and Eve multiplied like any other human today, by the process of sexual reproduction which results in giving birth to children. Perhaps you are asking about subsequent events, such as how their children multiplied or to whom they married.

This is an issue on which there are different reports. The widely accepted story is that the children were born in pairs and a male married any female who was not his twin. Another story is that the children married women from the Jinn and Hoor al-Ayn - this report being attributed to Imam Ja'far bin Muhammad al-Sadiq (see [Fath al-Bari 6/369](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/3563)). The Sunnis lean towards the first report, while the Shia sources I have seen seem to lean towards the second one.

Comment: @Umh Do you have an English translation for the report attributed to Imam Ja'far bin Muhammad al-Sadiq ? (The link provided above is in Arabic)

Comment: @Ahmed I do not have a translation but I can convey it: Ibn Hajar has cited that an unauthentic report exists in [قصص الأنبياء للثعلبي](https://archive.org/details/1215Pdf/page/n47/mode/2up?view=theater) which states that Imam Ja'far denied that Adam married his sons to his daughters and he stated that Adam's shariah was the same as ours. Rather Adam was told to marry Cain to a female Jinn in the form of a human, and Abel to a Hoor. Cain objected and this led to the sacrifice mentioned in the Quran 5:27.

Comment: Thank you for the summarized translation.