# Was incest permissible at some point ? Did Adam’s first children had to procreate between themselves?

Tags: children, adam-and-eve, ethics

We know incest is forbidden in Islam and other religions. But when we go back to the first human being on earth, prophet Adam, we know that he had children with his wife Eve. And as we are all coming from both of them, it means at some point incest had to happen right. Maybe I am wrong but I really want to understand this aspect. Maybe there is a good explanation for it. Was incest permisssible at that time only temporary ? Or were there more than 2 human being created right after Adam and Eve

Comment: See [How did Adam and Hawwa multiply?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/74262/)

Comment: I didn't downvote nor upvote, but I can't see any reasons for the downvotes. To those who downvoteted: please explain!

Answer (score -1):

Well it’s not mentioned in quran, but it’s believed that incest was allowed back then but later on it was forbidden. Allah hu alam.